# Why my ubuntu 16.04 when wake up from suspend, the brightness reset to maximum?

Tags: 16.04

I modified `/etc/rc.local` to set the brightness, but however when I suspend and wake it up, its brightness always reset to maximum.  What's wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: That's funny because mine occasionally resets to minimum when waking up.

Comment: You are experiencing the wonders of Power Management. Read `man pm-action`. It will show you how Ubuntu suspends and wakes up, and where to put your intervention to fix brightness.

Comment: I can't say why your brightness was resetting to min or max. But this will set brightness to your preferred setting automatically based on sunrise and sunset: http://askubuntu.com/questions/894460/automatically-adjust-display-brightness-based-on-sunrise-and-sunset/894470#894470