# Can't run xflux in Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04

I have already installed xflux. But when i run fluxgui in command line it says:fluxgui

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/fluxgui", line 17, in <module>
    from fluxgui.fluxapp import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxapp.py", line 3, in <module>
    from fluxgui import fluxcontroller, settings
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/fluxcontroller.py", line 1, in <module>
    from fluxgui import xfluxcontroller
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/fluxgui/xfluxcontroller.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pexpect
ImportError: No module named pexpect
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64-bit
Is there any better alternative to programs like xflux? My eyes strain while not using it.

Comment: Please try this `sudo -E pip install pexpect`

Comment: I'd also suggest upgrading (`sudo apt full-upgrade` or `sudo apt dist-upgrade`) as you should be using 16.04.5 LTS and your system is a lot of updates behind.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pexpect in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages

Comment: is the latest version stable?

Comment: There is a bash script that you can use which will work in any version: https://askubuntu.com/questions/894460/automatically-adjust-display-brightness-based-on-sunrise-and-sunset/894470#894470 I'm currently enhancing it if you have any suggestions.