# Is there an alternative to Redshift that allows for more customization like exact times where the display starts to shift color & transition duration?

Tags: colors, alternative

I am very new to Linux, so I apologize if my question is obvious to many people. I don't know if this is relevant, since I am still learning, but I am using the distro "pop! OS", which is built upon Ubuntu.

For Windows I use f.lux to tint my screen when it gets late, and when using Linux I have been using Redshift. My problem with Redshift however is that you are only able to specify **when** the red-shifting should begin, and you are not able to specify how quick the transition from normal colors, to the shifted colors will be. Does any alternative exist where you are able to specify both when the color shifting should begin, but also how quickly it will shift into the maximum specified tint?

Comment: You can specify the time dawn-time and dusk-time [as seen in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561748/resdhift-specify-multiple-time-periods). Additionally, if I'm not mistaken, Redshift is based on f.lux and you can also install f.lux on linux. Furthermore however, questions about pop!OS are off topic here at Askubuntu because Pop is not an official Ubuntu flavor but your question is on topic over at https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Also, if you're interested in screen brightness, there is [this answer about backlight brightness that adjusts throughout the day](https://askubuntu.com/a/894470/167115). Not sure how smooth the transition is but you might be able to adapt it to redshift somehow. But iirc, there should be a way to specify the transition length with redshift.